# Not able to pass post parameters from Android volley

Tags: php, android, android-volley

i am following a tutorial on androidhive, but i am not able to pass post parameters, their are certain solutions but none worked for me.

PHP CODE:

```
require("config.inc.php");

$organizationname = $_POST['organizationname'];
$date = $_POST["dates"];
//$date = "19-08-2015";
//$organizationname = "xyz123";

//initial query
$query2 = "SELECT rollno,studentname,`$date` FROM `attendencee` WHERE organizationname = '$organizationname' ";
```

As you can see there are commented variables, when i use them the code works fine, but when i try to use the values received, the error shows variables not defined.

CODE:

```
public class JsonRequestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private String TAG = JsonRequestActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnJsonObj, btnJsonArray;
    private TextView msgResponse;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // These tags will be used to cancel the requests
    private String tag_json_obj = "jobj_req", tag_json_arry = "jarray_req";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_json);

        btnJsonObj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnJsonObj);
        btnJsonArray = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnJsonArray);
        msgResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgResponse);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        btnJsonObj.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnJsonArray.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.hide();
    }

    /**
     * Making json object request
     * */
    private void makeJsonObjReq() {
        showProgressDialog();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                Const.URL_JSON_OBJECT, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                }) {

            /**
             * Passing some request headers
             * */
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("dates", "19-08-2015");
                params.put("organizationname", "xyx123");

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,
                tag_json_obj);

        // Cancelling request
        // ApplicationController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag_json_obj);       
    }

    /**
     * Making json array request
     * */
    private void makeJsonArryReq() {
        showProgressDialog();
        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Const.URL_JSON_ARRAY,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        msgResponse.setText("Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req,
                tag_json_arry);

        // Cancelling request
        // ApplicationController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag_json_arry);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnJsonObj:
            makeJsonObjReq();
            break;
        case R.id.btnJsonArray:
            makeJsonArryReq();
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: tried that too.. didn't work

Comment: You appear to be doing a GET request and encoding your parameters in JSON. I can't see how that could possibly end up as anything you could get directly out of `$_POST`. Are you sure you're following the tutorial correctly?

Comment: Hi! Have you tried my answer yet?

Comment: Hi! everyone, really sorry for replying so late.
I did figure out the solution by using volley's String method instead of makeJsonObjReq, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

1) Http method must be POST not Method.GET 
2) Change:

```
 @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("dates", "19-08-2015");
                params.put("organizationname", "xyx123");

                return params;
            }
```

to:

```
 @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {

        byte[] body = new byte[0];

        try {
            body = mJson.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Logcat.e(TAG, "Unable to gets bytes from JSON", e.fillInStackTrace());
        }
        return body;
    }
```

`mJson` is your `JSON` (String)

Comment: i don't get you..
how will i add parameters?

Comment: JSON string:` { "dates" : "19-08-2015", "organizationname" : "xyx123"}` Read about JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. "getParams" won't work. Suppose you want to post a user object to server, First you create a user json object then you post it like this:

```
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonBody.put("Email", email);
        jsonBody.put("Username", name1);
        jsonBody.put("Password", password);
        jsonBody.put("ConfirmPassword", password);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JsonObjectRequest strReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject jObj) {
            // do these if it request was successful
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // do these if it request has errors
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }
    };
```

Comment: i did try this, and was very positive that it will work, but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue has not been fixed, try my following code:

```
Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
stringMap.put("key1", "value1");
stringMap.put("key2", "value2");        
final String requestBody = buildRequestBody(stringMap);

...

public String buildRequestBody(Object content) {
    String output = null;
    if ((content instanceof String) ||
            (content instanceof JSONObject) ||
            (content instanceof JSONArray)) {
        output = content.toString();
    } else if (content instanceof Map) {
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        HashMap hashMap = (HashMap) content;
        if (hashMap != null) {
            Iterator entries = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while (entries.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
                builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
                entries.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
            }
            output = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Inside your POST Request, override 2 following methods:

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    try {
        return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
                requestBody, "utf-8");
        return null;
    }
}
```